# How to get the this window in Android

Tags: android, geolocation

I want to to show the current city & weather in screen like this

[image]

I don't have good knowledge in android widget.I want to do one app.Like below picture,.I have tried like this in manifest file :

```
<activity android:name=".WeatherActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

I really don't know what I want to do. I want to setup the size. How we can do? 
Another thing I want to get the current city from phone?

Comment: What are you trying to do? A widget? A dialog? A full-screen app? Also, these are two completely different questions.

Comment: I need to build like this widget. How to do? please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) will answer all your questions about the widget and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) will answer all your questions about getting a user's location.